# Simpson's rule in Python

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods

For a numerical methods class, I need to write a program to evaluate a definite integral with Simpson's composite rule. I already got this far (see below), but my answer is not correct. I am testing the program with f(x)=x, integrated over 0 to 1, for which the outcome should be 0.5. I get 0.78746... etc.
I know there is a Simpson's rule available in Scipy, but I really need to write it myself.

I suspect there is something wrong with the two loops. I tried "for i in range(1, n, 2)" and "for i in range(2, n-1, 2)" before, and this gave me a result of 0.41668333... etc.
I also tried "x += h" and I tried "x += i*h". The first gave me 0.3954, and the second option 7.9218.

```
# Write a program to evaluate a definite integral using Simpson's rule with
# n subdivisions

from math import *
from pylab import *

def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    h=(b-a)/n
    k=0.0
    x=a
    for i in range(1,n/2):
        x += 2*h
        k += 4*f(x)
    for i in range(2,(n/2)-1):
        x += 2*h
        k += 2*f(x)
    return (h/3)*(f(a)+f(b)+k)

def function(x): return x

print simpson(function, 0.0, 1.0, 100)
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: This may be due to truncation errors, did you check indeterminate values at any point?

Comment: did you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpsons_rule there is an algorithm listed in python2

Comment: Your code is practically identical to Wikipedia's sample implementation...

Comment: I think it's Python 2.7.3 (part of EPD 7.3).

Comment: I think it's Python 2.7.3 (part of EPD 7.3). And yes, I used the Wikipedia code as an example for the loops, but I did not completely understand how they made that loop work, so I tried to write it in a way I would understand it (that's the whole point of taking the class...). I basically tried to write the mathematical equation from my book (which is probably not the most elegant code, but my objective is more to understand the computing steps than to write the shortest code possible): h/3 * [f1 + 4*f2 + 2*f3 + 4*f4 + ... + 4*fn-1 + fn]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably forget to initialize `x` before the second loop, also, starting conditions and number of iterations are off. Here is the correct way:

```
def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    h=(b-a)/n
    k=0.0
    x=a + h
    for i in range(1,n/2 + 1):
        k += 4*f(x)
        x += 2*h

    x = a + 2*h
    for i in range(1,n/2):
        k += 2*f(x)
        x += 2*h
    return (h/3)*(f(a)+f(b)+k)
```

Your mistakes are connected with the notion of a loop invariant. Not to get into details too much, it's generally easier to understand and debug cycles which advance at the end of a cycle, not at the beginning, here I moved the `x += 2 * h` line to the end, which made it easy to verify where the summation starts. In your implementation it would be necessary to assign a weird `x = a - h` for the first loop only to add `2 * h` to it as the first line in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, I think it has more to do with the mathematical mistake I made (each loop indeed needed a different x as starting value; x1 and x2 respectively), because I came to this solution myself a few minutes ago, but put the line calculating x above the line calculating k. That gives the solution 0.4997333, and your solution gives 0.4802666. This confuses me, because in hindsight what you say makes more sense, putting the line calculating x at the end of the loop.

Comment: Also, more a math question than a Python question: according to my book, Simpson's should be more accurate than the trapezoidal rule. I also wrote a program for the trapezoidal rule. With n=100, the trapezoidal rule gives me the exact answer (0.5), but with implementation of Simpson's, it's 0.4802666. Any ideas on why? Is it my code?

Comment: Come on, you have a working wikipedia code and mine, both give 0.5 for n = 100, if your code gives anything different, it's not Simpson's rule, it's wrong, doesn't make sense to compare to that.

Comment: Also, Simpson's is not necessarily better than trapezoidal for every function and for every `n` (you can imagine an almost linear function with a narrow peak in the middle to trick Simpson's rule), it's just better for a given class of functions with `n` growing.

Comment: you can compare trapezoid to Simpson's on `f = lambda x: x * x` anytime, Simpson's must give exact answer, while trapezoidal must overshoot (as `x * x` is a convex function) for any given `n` (note that it must be an even number for Simpson's), on linear functions they both must give exact answer for any `n`.

Comment: also make sure that you pass `float`s as `a` and `b` otherwise `(a-b)/n` might be calculated incorrectly

Comment: You are totally right about the code - I thought I had the same one as you posted, but then I noticed that I still had my ranges as before (n/2 and n/2-1). Changing them to yours did the trick! And thanks for the extra information on Simpson's and the trapezoidal rule, much appreciated!!

Comment: Dear @unkulunkulu thanks for the code, but I do not know how to use it correctly? Could you please help? I have the integral $I**5=int_0^4 x^5 dx$ ... how would the code look like, if I would like to calculate my integral, if I would use your code? I always get some float errors :/ my n should be 2,4 ... to I get an accuracy of $10**-10$ ... hopefully you can help :)

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich I don't see your code nor errors. Also, imagine that I help everyone debug their program in the comments. It would be hard. Just as a guess, try running it with python 2 not 3

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do to make this code work is add a variable for a and b in the function bounds() and add a function in f(x) that uses the variable x. You could also implement the function and bounds directly into the simpsonsRule function if desired... Also, these are functions to be implimented into a program, not a program itself.

```
def simpsonsRule(n):

    """
    simpsonsRule: (int) -> float
    Parameters:
        n: integer representing the number of segments being used to 
           approximate the integral
    Pre conditions:
        Function bounds() declared that returns lower and upper bounds of integral.
        Function f(x) declared that returns the evaluated equation at point x.
        Parameters passed.
    Post conditions:
        Returns float equal to the approximate integral of f(x) from a to b
        using Simpson's rule.
    Description:
        Returns the approximation of an integral. Works as of python 3.3.2
        REQUIRES NO MODULES to be imported, especially not non standard ones.
        -Code by TechnicalFox
    """

    a,b = bounds()
    sum = float()
    sum += f(a) #evaluating first point
    sum += f(b) #evaluating last point
    width=(b-a)/(2*n) #width of segments
    oddSum = float()
    evenSum = float()
    for i in range(1,n): #evaluating all odd values of n (not first and last)
        oddSum += f(2*width*i+a)
    sum += oddSum * 2
    for i in range(1,n+1): #evaluating all even values of n (not first and last)
        evenSum += f(width*(-1+2*i)+a)
    sum += evenSum * 4
    return sum * width/3

def bounds():
    """
    Description:
        Function that returns both the upper and lower bounds of an integral.
    """
    a = #>>>INTEGER REPRESENTING LOWER BOUND OF INTEGRAL<<<
    b = #>>>INTEGER REPRESENTING UPPER BOUND OF INTEGRAL<<<
    return a,b

def f(x):
    """
    Description:
        Function that takes an x value and returns the equation being evaluated,
        with said x value.
    """
    return #>>>EQUATION USING VARIABLE X<<<
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def simps(f, a, b, N):   # N must be an odd integer
    """ define simpson method, a and b are the lower and upper limits of
    the interval, N is number of points, dx is the slice
        """
    integ = 0
    dx = float((b - a) / N)

    for i in range(1,N-1,2):
        integ += f((a+(i-1)*dx)) + 4*f((a+i*dx)) + f((a+(i+1)*dx))
        integral = dx/3.0 * integ
    
    # if number of points is even, then error araise
    if (N % 2) == 0:
      raise ValueError("N must be an odd integer.")
        

    return integral


def f(x):
    return x**2


integrate = simps(f,0,1,99)
print(integrate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this program for calculating definite integrals by using Simpson's 1/3 rule. You can increase your accuracy by increasing the value of the variable panels.

```
import numpy as np

def integration(integrand,lower,upper,*args):    
    panels = 100000
    limits = [lower, upper]
    h = ( limits[1] - limits[0] ) / (2 * panels)
    n = (2 * panels) + 1
    x = np.linspace(limits[0],limits[1],n)
    y = integrand(x,*args)
    #Simpson 1/3
    I = 0
    start = -2
    for looper in range(0,panels):
        start += 2
        counter = 0
        for looper in range(start, start+3):
            counter += 1
            if (counter ==1 or counter == 3):
                I += ((h/3) * y[looper])
            else:
                I += ((h/3) * 4 * y[looper])
    return I
```

For example:

```
def f(x,a,b):
    return a * np.log(x/b)
I = integration(f,3,4,2,5)
print(I)
```

will integrate 2ln(x/5) within the interval 3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

There is my code (i think that is the most easy method). I done this in jupyter notebook. 
The easiest and most accurate code for Simpson method is 1/3.

### Explanation

For standard method (a=0, h=4, b=12) and f=100-(x^2)/2

We got: 
n= 3.0, y0 = 100.0, y1 = 92.0, y2 = 68.0, y3 = 28.0,

So simpson method = h/3*(y0+4*y1+2*y2+y3) = 842,7 (this is not true).
Using 1/3 rule we got:

h = h/2= 4/2= 2 and then:

n= 3.0, y0 = 100.0, y1 = 98.0, y2 = 92.0, y3 = 82.0, y4 = 68.0, y5 = 50.0, y6 = 28.0,

Now we calculate the integral for each step (n=3 = 3 steps):

Integral of the first step: h/3*(y0+4*y1+y2) = 389.3333333333333

Integral of the second step: h/3*(y2+4*y3+y4) = 325.3333333333333

Integral of the third step: h/3*(y4+4*y5+y6) = 197.33333333333331

Sum all, and we get 912.0 AND THIS IS TRUE

```
x=0
b=12
h=4
x=float(x)
h=float(h)
b=float(b)
a=float(x)
def fun(x): 
    return 100-(x**2)/2
h=h/2
l=0  #just numeration
print('n=',(b-x)/(h*2))
n=int((b-a)/h+1)
y = []   #tablica/lista wszystkich y / list of all "y"
yf = []
for i in range(n):
    f=fun(x)
    print('y%s' %(l),'=',f)
    y.append(f)
    l+=1
    x+=h
print(y,'\n')
n1=int(((b-a)/h)/2)  
l=1
for i in range(n1):
    nf=(h/3*(y[+0]+4*y[+1]+y[+2]))
    y=y[2:]  # with every step, we deleting 2 first "y" and we move 2 spaces to the right, i.e. y2+4*y3+y4
    print('Całka dla kroku/Integral for a step',l,'=',nf)
    yf.append(nf)
    l+=1
print('\nWynik całki/Result of the integral =', sum(yf) )
```

At the beginning I added simple data entry:

```
d=None
while(True):
    print("Enter your own data or enter the word "test" for ready data.\n")
    x=input ('Enter the beginning of the interval (a): ') 
    if x == 'test':
        x=0
        h=4  #krok (Δx)
        b=12 #granica np. 0>12  
        #w=(20*x)-(x**2)  lub   (1+x**3)**(1/2)
        break
    h=input ('Enter the size of the integration step (h): ')
    if h == 'test':
        x=0
        h=4 
        b=12 
        break
    b=input ('Enter the end of the range (b): ')
    if b == 'test':
        x=0
        h=4  
        b=12 
        break 
    d=input ('Give the function pattern: ')
    if d == 'test':
        x=0
        h=4  
        b=12
        break
    elif d != -9999.9:
        break

x=float(x)
h=float(h)
b=float(b)
a=float(x)

if d == None or d == 'test':
    def fun(x): 
        return 100-(x**2)/2 #(20*x)-(x**2)
else:
    def fun(x): 
        w = eval(d)
        return  w
h=h/2
l=0  #just numeration
print('n=',(b-x)/(h*2))
n=int((b-a)/h+1)
y = []   #tablica/lista wszystkich y / list of all "y"
yf = []
for i in range(n):
    f=fun(x)
    print('y%s' %(l),'=',f)
    y.append(f)
    l+=1
    x+=h
print(y,'\n')
n1=int(((b-a)/h)/2)  
l=1
for i in range(n1):
    nf=(h/3*(y[+0]+4*y[+1]+y[+2]))
    y=y[2:]
    print('Całka dla kroku/Integral for a step',l,'=',nf)
    yf.append(nf)
    l+=1
print('\nWynik całki/Result of the integral =', sum(yf) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of implementing Simpson's rule for integral sinX with a = 0 and b = pi/4. And use 10 panels for the integration

```
def simpson(f, a, b, n):
  x = np.linspace(a, b, n+1)
  w = 2*np.ones(n+1); w[0] = 1.0; w[-1] = 1;
  for i in range(len(w)):
      if i % 2 == 1:
          w[i] = 4
  width = x[1] - x[0]
  area = 0.333 * width * np.sum( w*f(x))
  return area

f = lambda x: np.sin(x)
a = 0.0; b = np.pi/4

areaSim = simpson(f, a, b, 10)
print(areaSim)
```